# Как добавить ссылку на службу в референс?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ссылки, службы

Нужно добавить в Reference System.ServiceProcess.dll, но когда я клацаю правой кнопкой мышки  по referene(они же ссылки в русской версии)->добавить ссылку на службу->дополнительно...->добавить веб ссылку->Обзор серверов UDDI в локальной сети, то там пусто...

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: мб скачать надо,насколько понимаю в локальной сети только ваш пк

Comment: требует адрес url

Comment: Так вам ссылку на службу нужно или на System.ServiceProcess.dll, это разные вещи

Comment: System.ServiceProcess.dll
я просто поискал и мне выдало, что это ссылка на службу, увы дилетант в этом вопросе

Answer (score 3):

Щелкаем правой кнопкой на проект->Добавить->Cсылка...->Cборки->Ищем System.ServiceProcess и ставим галочку ->Ок